# Save Checkbox value in SharePoint list item SPFx

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepoint-rest-api, office-ui-fabric

I am using below code in SPFx to create checkbox

```
export interface IExampleState {
  isChecked: boolean;
}

constructor(props: IExampleProps) {
    super(props);
(this);
    this.state = {
      isChecked: false
    };
  }



 <Checkbox
    checked={this.state.isChecked}
    label="checkbox"
 />
```

Now, how shall I change my value to true on check and false on uncheck and save same in SharePoint using Rest API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the state value on change event of "Checkbox" and use the state value as mentioned below:

```
    private async createItem() {  
        return sp.web.lists.getByTitle('ListName')
              .items.add({  
                     ColumnName: this.state.isChecked  
              })
              .then((result) => {
                     return result;
                     console.log("Added");
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                     return null;
                     console.log("Error:- " + error);
              });
    }
```